# FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInResponse - ThreadAbortException

Tags: wif, windows-identity

I've been tasked with automating the setup of our applications by developing a tool to allow our support team to easily setup and configure this application.

I verified that the application (originally setup by hand) worked before I began mucking with the settings.

I feel like I am almost there BUT the STS keeps throwing a ThreadAbortException after calling ProcessSignInResponse. I'm almost certain the problem in is in a configuration file because I have not altered the code base, only the configuration files.

I've seen other posts about this being a 'known' issue and how to just catch and ignore it BUT this only started happening since I began changing things.

Does anyone know of any other things to check for that could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So as I thought this was in the configuration. A WCF service config file had a bad cert thumbprint.